# Catch-22 with parserOptions and exclude

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm wanting to add `@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises` to my ESLint rules and am having difficulties.

That requires `parserOptions`.

Here's my .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2017,
    project: './tsconfig.json'
  },
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier'
  ],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises': ['error'],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off'
  }
};
```

and my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": ["ES2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

The catch is the `exclude`. I don't want my tests (specs) to be compiled to the `outDir`. But this causes the following error when I run ESLint:

> error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for
>   @typescript-eslint/parser. The file does not match your project
>   config: src/index.spec.ts. The file must be included in at least one
>   of the projects provided

(Script is `"lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts\""` )

I **do** want to lint my tests.

Everything worked fine until I added `parserOptions` - and I need that for the `no-floating-promises` rule.

The [typescript-eslint FAQ](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/FAQ.md#i-get-errors-telling-me-the-file-must-be-included-in-at-least-one-of-the-projects-provided) says:

> To fix this, simply make sure the include option in your tsconfig includes every single file you want to lint.

The catch is that I'm creating a library, and I don't want to publish the test files.

How can I build only the files I want to publish to one directory while still linting all the files? (I would like to keep the build as simple as possible.)

Comment: Why not have two different TSConfig files?  One for building the project for publishing and the other for developing against it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use two `tsconfig.json`s in my projects.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": ["ES2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

**tsconfig.build.json**

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "exclude": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

To build the project run `tsc -p tsconfig.build.json`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!